# cannot create compressed spitted file using 7zip E_NOTIMPL

Tags: 7-zip

I'm trying to compress a folder protect it with password and split if the file size is bigger than 3333MB using 7z.

```
7za a  -ptesttest -mhe=on  -mx0 -v3333m /tmp/Test.7z  /tmp/xxx/

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)


System error:
E_NOTIMPL
```

but when I do:

```
7z a -ptesttest -mhe=on  -mx0 /tmp/Test.7z  /tmp/xxx/

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Scanning

Updating archive /tmp/Test.7z

Compressing  xxx/test-day.jpg      

Everything is Ok
```

I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score -1, accepted):

heh it's working now.

Few days have passed (maybe I've restarted my computer several times) and it's working without problem.

It may be than some depencancy was not loaded properly that restart solved

Comment: I've just installed 7z version 16.02 on Debian, and I get the same "E_NOTIMPL" error when I attempt to use the -v command... I've also checked for available package updates and rebooted my server a few times. Any ideas on how to get volume split to work? Besides just waiting a day or so :)

Comment: Okay, this is nuts. I waited 3 hours after installation. Server was not rebooted. Putty'd back in, tried again... and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that archive file name has `.7z` extension. I got 'System ERROR: E_NOTIMPL' when I tried

```
7z a archive.z myfile.txt
```

It should be

```
7z a archive.7z myfile.txt
```