# Getting E_NOTIMPL error when using -v option with 7zip on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, compression, zip, 7-zip

Running Debian 9, installed 7-zip 16.02 (64-bit) from debian repo.

I'm attempting to create a split 7zip archive, and I receive this error message:

```
7z a dir1.zip dir1 -v1k

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU J3455 @ 1.50GHz (506C9),ASM,AES-NI)



System ERROR:
E_NOTIMPL
```

What's the deal? [Older questions on this same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1270073/cannot-create-compressed-spitted-file-using-7zip-e-notimpl) are not helpful.

Is the volume split feature not implemented in this specific version of 7-zip?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use Debian default kernel or one of your own? What filesystem type are you on when launching the command? You can try prefixing it with `strace` that will give you more details on the OS commands that `7z`  is calling to pinpoint which operation generated the error `E_NOTIMPL`. Also `1k` seems awfully small, why should a small value? Did you try changing it, using `m` for example and do you have then the same problem? It is certainly not a `7z` problem I have the same version, and the same command as yours works okay (on Ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried multiple sizes and types (b, k, m, g). 1k was used just for testing. I even tried incorrect size types (like w) to make sure that it is recognizing the types correctly.

Comment: What the heck... I just tried it again... its working now! What is up with that?! What is happening between "then" and "now"? It's been 3 hours. The server was not rebooted after my initial reboots. It stayed online. :o I logged in via multiple putty sessions both then and now. This might need testing in a VM to see if "time after installation" is a factor for this issue. Because this correlates to the SO question I referenced in the original question... bizarre!

Comment: Did content of directory change? Permissions? Amount of free space to create archive? Etc.